# Attempting to access Nginx from www (public internet network)

Tags: nginx, nat, netplan

I have Nginx running successfully on my local network. Before I proceed with the question, here are the IP addresses:

1. Ubuntu Server Local IP Address: `192.168.29.110`
2. Internet IPv4 IP Address: `45.8.202.88` (ports forwarded: 80, 443)

Here is my Netplan config file:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.29.110/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        search: []
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.29.1
  version: 2
```

I am able to see Nginx landing page successfully on 192.168.29.110 on local area network but I get connection error when visiting dedicated IP address of my internet (45.8.202.88) What changes do I have to make to my Nginx config file as well as my Netplan? Here is my Nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name 45.8.202.88;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.29.110;  # Update this line
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
```

Ports 80/443 are open as check on [port checker](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/). Also, ufw firewall is disabled on the Ubuntu server. Another side note, this dedicated IPv4 internet IP address is from a connected VPN. My ISP doesn't allow port forwarding and dedicated IP address, so I had to grab one from a VPN.

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your nginx config, but something sends a RST. Check with your VPN provider. Furthermore port 443 is identified as OpenVPN by `nmap`; are you *certain* that port forwarding is set up correctly for that IP?

Comment: Port checker websites seem to think both ports are open on the VPN IP, and this is probably the best case scenario for me till now after days of testing since both ports are closed on my ISP connection and there is no way for me to forward them. I'm both ecstatic and lost at the same time. I can't seem to figure out why it won't work.

Comment: How do you know those ports are forwarded to you?

Comment: I don't. As a matter of fact all I know is that these ports are open from port checker websites. My knowledge on networking is very limited and is why I'm here asking for help.

Comment: Then they don't. The VPN probably shares the public IP with multiple customers, and what you're seeing is their VPN server. You need to find a VPN provider which lets you forward traffic. BTW: you don't want a reverse proxy proxying to yourself....

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Interesting ... thanks. So, I need to find a VPN which not only allows port forwarding but allow allows forwarding traffic? @vidarlo It was already hard enough finding a VPN which would allow port forwarding.. oh boy.

Comment: You said you didn't set up port forwarding?

Comment: So.. this VPN that I'm using only allows one randomly assigned port to be forwarded (in my case 35468). That's what it claims to do anyway, but when I connected to the VPN and checked the opened ports to the dedicated IP I was provided on the port checker websites, I saw 80/443 open and I thought it was just coincidental and favorable to me. Guess that's not how it works?

Comment: Your understanding is correct-they give you one random port.

Comment: What does `nginx -T` say

Comment: It says, syntax is ok @Turdie

Comment: I'm thinking of taking a different approach at this problem, @vidarlo. If you could have a look at my [new question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1153999/connecting-nginx-server-to-openvpn-and-accessing-it-from-the-internet), I'd be grateful. It comes with it's own challenges.

Comment: `server_name 45.8.202.88;` - don't do this. Seriously. Use the default server if you can't provision DNS.

Comment: Flagged for movement to superuser.com as home and enduser questions are offtopic