# Connecting Nginx Server to OpenVPN and Accessing it from the Internet

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, openvpn, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an Nginx server running on my local network, and I want to make it accessible from the internet via an OpenVPN connection. Here are the details of my setup:

- Ubuntu Server Local IP Address: `192.168.29.110`
- OpenVPN Access Server IP Address: `139.59.60.64`

**Notes**:

1. OpenVPN Access Server is running on a DigitalOcean Ubuntu Server (called *OpenVPN-server* hereon)
2. Nginx is running on a local Ubuntu Server at home (called *Nginx-server* hereon)
3. Home network (ISP) doesn't allow dedicated IP / port forwarding due to which I'm unable to access my *Nginx-server* from outside the LAN network. Therefore the goal is to connect local *Nginx-server* to *OpenVPN-server* so as to use the IP address of the VPN connected and thereby allow *Nginx-server* to be accessible from the word wide web (public internet).
4. UFW is disabled on both *OpenVPN-server* as well as *Nginx-server*.
5. DigitalOcean firewall is disabled.

**Network Configuration on Nginx-server**:
Netplan configuration (/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml):

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.29.110/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        search: []
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.29.1
  version: 2
```

**Nginx Configuration on Nginx-server**:
Nginx configuration file (/etc/nginx/sites-available/default):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name 139.59.60.64;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.29.110;  # Update this line
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
```

**Challenges and Questions**:

1. Replacing OpenVPN Dashboard with Nginx Landing Page:

- I currently access the OpenVPN Access Server dashboard from the IP
  address `139.59.60.64`. After establishing a connection from
  *Nginx-server* to the *OpenVPN-server*, I want to replace the dashboard
  with my local Nginx landing page. How can I achieve this?

2. Making Nginx Accessible from the Internet via OpenVPN:

- After connecting to the *OpenVPN-server*, what changes do I need to make in my Nginx configuration file and Netplan configuration on Nginx-server to access my *Nginx-server* from the internet?

Comment: You also need some routing on top of the VPN so I would suggest a gateway like opnsense

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to create a static route to route the vpn network, where the devices are in who connect over the vpn. to the host network.

And you need to make sure that the vpn ports and traffic are allowed.

To make sure that the nginx pages are served you need to make sure that nginx runs on port 80/443 and has a couple of vhosts to serve content. Probably the openvpn access server has its own webserver